# Is there any way to change class of view controller in interface builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I've create UIPageViewController in interface builder. Now, I'd like to change its' class to UIViewController but it seems I cannot do that apart from deleting current controller and creating new one and re-adding all segues.

Custom class property only shows UIPageViewController classes and if I set it to UIViewController it just reverts back.

Comment: If the view is a UIPageView, it wants a (subclass of) UIPageViewController. Not much you can do about that.

Comment: Click the vc in interfacebuild and hit CMD+option+3 > set custom class but note: setting an incompatible class (which you can do via texteditor) would lead to crash at runtime which is why it doesnt work for you in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out you can edit storyboard xml file and just change pageViewController tag into viewController tag and it works.